# Where are the API docs for org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra for Spark 1.3.x?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a Spark job that uses Spark-Cassandra connector to connect to Cassandra from spark and then runs queries on Spark/Cassandra using Spark SQL. I was wondering where I could find the API docs for this? Looking at the api here

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package

It would seem like the package doesn't even exit (it does, I'm using it right now).

Here is the only link I can find that references accessing Cassandra from SparkSQL

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#accessing-cassandra-with-sparksql-since-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new module is inside of the Spark Cassandra Connector not the apache Spark project.

The new DataSource code is described in the new Dataframes section with the syntax for both SparkSQL and programatic access.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md

The code itself which you are looking for is

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra

Answer (score 0):

The connector README shows that the [docs are hosted](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#hosted-api-docs) through the datastax github site:

The link for the 1.3 docs is:

http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/1.3.1/spark-cassandra-connector/#org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.package